# XSL media:content - Trimming strings in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Can anyone tell me how to select the URL from this:

```
<media:content url="http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TEDTalks_video/~5/aZWq6PY05YE/TimBrown_2009G.mp4" fileSize="57985745" type="video/mp4" />
```

I want to:

1. Create a link to this file:
2. Trim the URL from:

   http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TEDTalks_video/~5/aZWq6PY05YE/TimBrown_2009G.mp4

to:

```
TimBrown_2009G
```

and then take: TimBrown_2009G and use it as part of a URL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Selecting the URL.** You just need to make sure that you have the correct namespace URI.

```
<xsl:value-of xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
              select="media:content/@url"/>
```

**Trimming down the URL.** How to do this best depends on whether you are using XSLT 1 or 2, since the latter has better string handling functions from XPath 2.0.

If you are using XSLT 1, you might want to create a helper template to return the last segment out of a delimited string:

```
<xsl:template name="last-substring-after">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, $separator)">
      <xsl:call-template name="last-substring-after">
        <xsl:with-param name="string"
                        select="substring-after($string, $separator)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separator"
                        select="$separator"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can make use of that to extract the last segment of the URL, and proceed to extract the part before the dot. Assuming the URL is in variable `url`:

```
<xsl:variable name="name">
  <xsl:call-template name="last-substring-after">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$url"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'/'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, '.')"/>
```