# XSL Get filename from URL

Tags: xslt

I need to get just the filename from this url:

```
http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TEDTalks_video/~5/XT8k_DqlzGc/KarenArmstrong_2009G.mp4
```

So I need to get:

```
KarenArmstrong_2009G
```

I need the filename so I can add .jpg to it and another base url.

Comment: Can you use javascript to get your filename? - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511761/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500067/xsl-mediacontent

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(@"http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TEDTalks_video/~5/XT8k_DqlzGc/KarenArmstrong_2009G.mp4");
        string filename = "";

        filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath); /// filename="KarenArmstrong_2009G.mp4"
        filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.Length - 4);/// filename="KarenArmstrong_2009G"
        MessageBox.Show(filename);
    }
```