# Parsing an mp3 file name from a url using regex in xsl

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xml-parsing

I have an rss feed that I need to transform into a different XML schema.  And at the same time, parse the mp3 file name into a new field. I have an xsl that seems to work for the rest of the transform (written for me), but I'm not sure how to make this:

```
    <enclosure url="http://www.fffff.com/pts/redirect.mp3/audio.xxyy.org/musiccheck/musiccheck20130118pod.mp3" length="0" type="audio/mpeg"></enclosure>
```

turn into this:

```
    <fileIdentifier source="Theme">musiccheck20130118pod</fileIdentifier>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the complete solution in XSLT 1.0 without using regex:**

```
<xsl:template match="enclosure">
<xsl:variable name="url" select="./@url"/>
<xsl:variable name="name">
  <xsl:call-template name="last-substring-after">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$url"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'/'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<fileIdentifier source="Theme">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, '.')"/>
</fileIdentifier>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="last-substring-after">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, $separator)">
      <xsl:call-template name="last-substring-after">
        <xsl:with-param name="string"
                        select="substring-after($string, $separator)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separator"
                        select="$separator"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output will be-**

```
<fileIdentifier source="Theme">musiccheck20130118pod</fileIdentifier>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500067/xsl-mediacontent-trimming-strings-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about your URL format, namely that the file name is the last thing with .mp3 in it:

```
/[\S\s]*?url="[\S\s]*?\/([\w]+?\.mp3)".*?/$1/
```

Just noting the second part of what you want to get, would be:

```
/[\S\s]*?url="[\S\s]*?\/([\w]+?\.mp3)".*?/<fileIdentifier source="Theme">$1</fileIdentifier>/
```